# Linux command line starting with username@shadow:

Tags: linux, centos7

When I log into a linux server, normally I see command line starting with `username@servername`.  Recently, I've noticed it is changed to `username@shadow`.  I searched the net but I couldn't find any information.  Could some one please help?  Thank you in advance.

Example:

`root@servername:/devops` changed to `root@shadow:/devops`

output of `echo $PS1`: `\u@\h:$PWD\n#`

Comment: Please [add](https://serverfault.com/posts/1050882/edit) the output of `echo $PS1` to your question.

Comment: here the output:

$ echo $PS1
\u@\h:$PWD\n$

Comment: then could it be your host name changed somehow? Please check `hostname -f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your input and response.  I was attempting to make some changes but decided to reboot the server first.  It came back with what I was expecting without doing anything else.  I am not sure what caused the difference.  Again, thank you for your time.

I am not sure how to close or mark this question as RESOLVED.  If possible please educate me and I will mark it as "RESOVLED".  Thanks again.

Comment: You mark it as resolved by clicking the outline of the tick mark next to the answer that helped you so that it turns solid green.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow your hostname changed to shadow that's why it showing you shadow.

Comment: Thank you for your response